# MySQL Error – User has Exceeded The ‘Max_questions’ Resource (Current Value: 1000)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 Application which uses MySQL Database.In my application Testing phase i am inserting lots of data for checking functionality of my application.After inserting lots of entries i am getting Mysql error like,

```
Mysql2::Error: User 'Databasename' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 10000): SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`username` = 'admin' LIMIT 1
```

How to solve this error.Is there any Limit in Mysql ,if so how to override this.

Any help is Appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for testing purposes you can define it such as:

```
SET @MAX_QUESTIONS=<your new value>;
```

in MySQL

or:

```
update user set max_questions = 10000 where user = 'you name or root';
```

if you put `0` for `max_questions` - it means unlimited

Note: You may have to restart you Mysql server to take effect

---

of course you can just flush privileges:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Flush the privileges to make the changes take affect. "flush privileges;"