# Error Number: 1226 User 'testdb' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 75000)error in codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter

> Error Number: 1226

User `'testdb'` has exceeded the `'max_questions'` resource `(current value: 75000)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Error – User has Exceeded The ‘Max\_questions’ Resource (Current Value: 1000)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873094/mysql-error-user-has-exceeded-the-max-questions-resource-current-value-100)

Comment: testdb is username and current value shows maximum number of connections allowed from this user so grant prilevege on `user testdb with max query 100` like this

Comment: how to grant privillage in codeigniter

Comment: @girdgird Its not in codeigniter itself read the link given above. there is the solution for your problem!